# KeyError in Python Program but not in interpreter?

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is the program i am trying to implement **Prims Algorithm** for Minimum Spanning Tree. My problem is that when I execute the program as a whole it shows the **KeyError : 7** :[image: Porgram run as a whole]

[image: When Executed in IDLE]

But when i execute the error causing portion in Interpreter it shows **no error** ?

My Code :

```
edges = {
            'A':{'D':1,'B':3},
            'B':{'A':3,'C':4},
            'C':{'B':4,'D':5,'A':2,'E':7},
            'D':{'A':1,'C':5,'E':6},
            'E':{'D':6,'C':7}
        }

# here NULL represented by -1 and Infinity represented by 1000

vertices = {
            'A':[1000,-1],
            'B':[1000,-1],
            'C':[1000,-1],
            'D':[1000,-1],
            'E':[1000,-1]
            }

def EXTRACTMIN():
    low = 'A'
    for key in vertices.keys():
        if vertices[low][0]>vertices[key][0]:
            low=key
    del vertices[low]
    return low

vertices['A'][0]=0

while not(vertices=={}):
    u=EXTRACTMIN()
    print(str(u)+" ")
    for v in [x for x in edges[u].keys()]:
        if v in vertices and edges[u][v]<vertices[v][0]:
            vertices[v][0]=edges[u][v]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the problem is in the function `EXTRACTMIN`

first you delete the key `A` from `vertices` because `A` is the minimum.

then, when calling again the function `EXTRACTMIN` you try to delete it again (since `vertices[low][0]>vertices[key][0]` is always `False`) but you already delete the `A` and its not exist in `vertices`.

you also not putting it back in the while loop becuase of the condition `v in vertices` and we know that `A` is not there